# get specific checkbox click event from a form array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that each row is a form. In on cell of a row is a delete button. I need a jquery modal dialog confirmation for delete when a check box clicked.
I tryied the javascipt incuded but working only for the firstn row.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog").hide();
});
$('#Wcheckboxcd1').click(function(e) {
    var form = $("form").attr("id"); 
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      buttons : {
        "Διαγραφή" : function() {
          document.getElementById(form).submit();
          $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Ακύρωση" : function() {
        document.getElementById(form).Wcheckboxcd.checked = 0;
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    }); 
})
```

Comment: Use class for checkbox. Don't use same ID for multiple checkbox elements

Comment: Yes I hava the same ID for all checkboxes of each form bau how to get click for the specific checkbox?

Comment: fist of all, you should understand that ID should be unique for html elements. Instead of putting IDs, you should add class on checkboxes & then use class to bind the checkbox events. Use this to bind, `$('.Wcheckboxcd1')`

Comment: Dear Apul, yes thats it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Change:

   ```
   var form = $("form").attr("id")
   ```

   ... to be:

   ```
   var form = $(this).closest('tr').find('form').attr('id');
   ```

   This selects the form from within the row of the "delete" button, rather than always the first `form`. For more info, see the documentation for [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest).
2. You are re-using the ID `Wcheckboxcd1`. ID's must be unique across a page. Use a class instead, or a `name` attribute, seeing as you're using forms.

Note also that it's quite redundant for you to use `document.getElementById`, when you are close to having the jQuery object containing the form element in the first place. Consider using code like below instead;

```
$('[name="Wcheckboxcd1"]').click(function(e) {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      buttons : {
        "Διαγραφή" : function() {
          $(this).closest('tr').find('form').submit();
          $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Ακύρωση" : function() {
          this.checked = false;
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    }); 
})
```

.. the above assumes you've changed your:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Wcheckboxcd1" />
```

to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Wcheckboxcd1" />
```

Comment: Dear Matt the problem is on checkbox id. I have the same ID on all checkboxes.
So the $('#Wcheckboxcd1').click(function(e) { is not working. I thing I need to use $form.('#Wcheckboxcd1').click(function(e) { but I dont know how.